# Which word to use to describe the fact that something has increased by a factor of 8

Tags: word-usage

I would like to express / rephrase the following fact to be more concise:

I have 10 rabbits and I want to write: The rabbits multiply each year by a factor of 8.

Usually I would use the word **octuplicate**: The number of rabbits octuplicates each year.

I'm not sure if the word **octuplicates** should be avoided, because it seems not too widely used, and it makes my sentence also not much shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have 10 rabbits and I want to write: The rabbits multiply **eightfold** each year.

Merriam-Webster

> -fold suffix

> Definition of -fold (Entry 5 of 5)

> 1 : multiplied by (a specified number) : times —in adjectives "*[Profits showed] a sixfold increase*" and adverbs "*[I will] repay you tenfold*."

> 2 : having (so many) parts "threefold aspect of the problem"

You say

> Usually I would use the word octuplicate: The number of rabbits octuplicates each year.

Usually? Really? I can find no instance of "to octuplicate" as a verb. The OED includes it as a noun but also marks it as "rare" - It seems to be an adaptation of "duplicate". The example given is used humorously: "*1994   Time 4 Apr. 88/1   Once a year, the government sends you a W-2 form, which you fill out in something like octuplicate.*"

Comment: Well at least I use it usually. The noun octuplets seems to be more common? Or is this also very rare.

Comment: @stephanmg You misunderstand: the verb does not seem to exist, and the noun is rare. The OED marks the noun as *"occurring less than 0.01 times per million words"* and remarks *These are almost exclusively terms which are not part of normal discourse* and *would be unknown to most people.*

Comment: Thank you @Greybeard. I used it in scientific communications. So I should also not use it there.

Comment: @stephanmg You should not use it in scientific communications (or any sort of communications.)

Answer (score 1):

The verb is **to octuple**

verb: octuple; 3rd person present: octuples; past tense: octupled; past participle: octupled; gerund or present participle: octupling

**make or become eight times as numerous or as large.**

"the new town populations have trebled the additions to the rural community, and in the case of Massachusetts have octupled them"

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/octuple

Usage has declined markedly in recent decades:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=octuple&direct_url=t4%3B%2Coctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOCTUPLE%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Coctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOctuple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOCTUPLE%3B%2Cc0

**Multiply eightfold** would be more contemporary English, and more easily understood.

Comment: So, will *octuple* be understood by most people especially in science? According to the answer by @Greybeard then *multiply eightfold* would be redundant since the suffix *-fold* already implies *multiplied*? So better should say *increase eightfold*?

Comment: @stephanmg *So, will octuple be understood by most people especially in science?* In my opinion, "octuple" should not be used. It is a very rare verb - it is simply not idiomatic in any context. It looks strange, regardless of whether you are a scientist or not. ++ There is nothing wrong with *The rabbits multiply eightfold each year.* but *The rabbit population/numbers show an eightfold increase, year on year* may be what you want.

Comment: That is true. Still it is probably originating from an adaption of the Latin word "duplicare" I guess, so it could still be useful to know but for the general public probably not suitable - especially if I want to communicate something without confusion.